# How can I get the location of a TextBlock's TextTrimming

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

If I have a long string of text in which the font size and family is adjustable, and it gets texttrimmed a few lines into the TextBlock's window, how do I get the spot or IndexOf or whatever of the point where the string is cut off?

I guess one way to put this is, like an article that spans two pages, I would like to get the indexof the end of the first page so I can know the next word in the article to begin on the second page.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the cutoff point by iteratively calling `GetPositionFromCharIndex`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's an option for a TextBlock.